# Mobile app/API security: will a hardcoded access key suffice?

Tags: rest, api, security, mobile, jwt

I'm building a mobile app which allows users to find stores and discounts near their location.  The mobile app gets that information from the server via a REST API, and I obviously want to protect that API.

1. Would it be enough to hardcode an access key (128 bit) into the mobile app, and send it on every request (enforcing https),  and then check if it matches the server key? I am aware of JWT, but I believe using it or other token-based approach will give me more flexibility but not necessarily more security.
2. As far as I can see the only problem with this approach is that I become vulnerable to a malicious developer on our team. Would there be a way to solve this?

Comment: If it is hardcoded in the app then someone can definitely retreive that key and use it for their own purposes. Whether by looking through direct source code (the dev you mention) or a decomplied source, you have put access to the key in everyone's hands who owns the app.

Comment: @Michael What do you suggest then?

Comment: I really don't think it's possible... https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219028/how-to-safeguard-a-rest-api-for-only-trusted-mobile-applications

Comment: More security: take a look at authorization grant flow with PKCE extension in oAuth. The [Best Current Practice](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics) doc is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as discussed many times here, what you want to achieve is not technically possible in a way that could be called secure. You can't authenticate the client, you can only authenticate people. The reason is that anything you put into a client will be fully available to people using it, so they can reproduce any request it makes.

Anything below is just a thought experiment.

Your approach of adding a static key, and sending it with every request is a very naive attempt. As an attacker, it would be enough for me to inspect one single request created by your app and then I would have the key to make any other request.

A very slightly better approach would be to store a key in your app and sign requests with it (instead of sending the actual key), like for example to create a hmac of the request with the key and add that as an additional request header. That's better, because I would have to disassemble the app to get the key - more work which could deter me, but very much possible.

As a next step, that secret key could be generated upon the first use of your app, and there we are getting close to as good as this could get. Your user installs the app, you generate a key, store it in the appropriate keystore of your platform, and register it with the user. From then on, on your backend you require every request to be signed (eg. the hmac method above) with the key associated with your user. The obvious problem is how you would assign keys - and such a key would still authenticate a user, and not his device or client, but at least from a proper keystore on a mobile platform, it would not be straightforward to get the key without rooting/jailbraking.But nothing would keep an attacker from installing the app on a rooted device or an emulator.

So the bottomline is, you can't prevent people from accessing your api with a different client. However, in the vast majority of cases they wouldn't want to anyway. If you really want to protect it, it should not be public, and a mobile app is not an appropriate platform.

Comment: Perfectly described. It is clear now and makes sense.

Comment: One question: would you be able to inspect my request, as you said, even if I'm using HTTPS? Otherwise my method would not be less secure than the others.

Comment: If I control the client (and I do in this scenario), yes of course.

Answer (score 1):

## YOUR PROBLEM

> Would it be enough to hardcode an access key (128 bit) into the mobile app, and send it on every request (enforcing https), and then check if it matches the server key?

Well no, because every secret you hide in a mobile app, is not anymore a secret, because will be accessible to everyone that wants to spend some time to reverse engineer your mobile app or to perform a MitM attack against it in a device he controls.

On the article [How to Extract an API key from a Mobile App by Static Binary Analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis) I show how easy is to extract a secret from the binary, but I also show a good approach to hide it, that makes it hard to reverse engineer:

> It's time to look for a more advanced technique to hide the API key in a way that will be very hard to reverse engineer from the APK, and for this we will make use of native C++ code to store the API key, by leveraging the JNI interface which uses NDK under the hood.

While the secret may be hard to reverse engineer it will be easy to extract with a MitM attack, and that is what I talk about in the article [Steal that API key with a MitM Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack):

> So, in this article you will learn how to setup and run a MitM attack to intercept https traffic in a mobile device under your control, so that you can steal the API key. Finally, you will see at a high level how MitM attacks can be mitigated.

If you read the article you will learn how an attacker will be able to extract any secret you transmit over https to your API server, therefore a malicious developer in your team  will not be your only concern.

You can go and learn how to implement certificate pinning to protect your https connection to the API server, and I also have wrote an article on it, entitled [Securing Https with Certificate Pinning on Android](https://blog.approov.io/securing-https-with-certificate-pinning-on-android):

> In this article you have learned that certificate pinning is the act of associating a domain name with their expected X.509 certificate, and that this is necessary to protect trust based assumptions in the certificate chain. Mistakenly issued or compromised certificates are a threat, and it is also necessary to protect the mobile app against their use in hostile environments like public wifis, or against DNS Hijacking attacks.
>
> Finally you learned how to prevent MitM attacks with the implementation of certificate pinning in an Android app that makes use of a network security config file for modern Android devices, and later by using TrustKit package which supports certificate pinning for both modern and old devices.

Sorry but I need to inform you that certificate pinning can be bypassed in a device the attacker controls, and I show how it can be done in the article entitled [Bypass Certificate Pinning](https://blog.approov.io/bypassing-certificate-pinning):

> In this article you will learn how to repackage a mobile app in order to make it trust custom ssl certificates. This will allow us to bypass certificate pinning.

Despite certificate pinning can be bypassed it is important to always use it to secure the connection between your mobile app and API server.

So and now what, am I doomed to fail in defending my API server... Hope still exists, keep reading!

## DEFENDING THE API SERVER

> The mobile app gets that information from the server via a REST API, and I obviously want to protect that API.

Protecting an API server for a mobile app is possible, and it can be done by using the Mobile App Attestation concept.

Before I go in detail to explain the Mobile App Attestation concept is important to we first clarify an usual misconception among developers, the difference between the **WHO** and the **WHAT** is accessing your API server.

### The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

To better understand the differences between the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are accessing an API server, let’s use this picture:

[image: Man in the Middle Attack]

The Intended Communication Channel represents the mobile app being used as you expected, by a legit user without any malicious intentions, using an untampered version of the mobile app, and communicating directly with the API server without being man in the middle attacked.

The actual channel may represent several different scenarios, like a legit user with malicious intentions that may be using a repackaged version of the mobile app, a hacker using the genuine version of the mobile app, while man in the middle attacking it, to understand how the communication between the mobile app and the API server is being done in order to be able to automate attacks against your API. Many other scenarios are possible, but we will not enumerate each one here.

I hope that by now you may already have a clue why the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are not the same, but if not it will become clear in a moment.

The **WHO** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

> [OAUTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)
>
> Generally, OAuth provides to clients a "secure delegated access" to server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials. Designed specifically to work with Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), OAuth essentially allows access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization server, with the approval of the resource owner. The third party then uses the access token to access the protected resources hosted by the resource server.
>
> [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/)
>
> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.

While user authentication may let the API server know **WHO** is using the API, it cannot guarantee that the requests have originated from **WHAT** you expect, the original version of the mobile app.

Now we need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling the API server, and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of the mobile app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around with the API server, using a tool like Postman?

For your surprise you may end up discovering that It can be one of the legit users using a repackaged version of the mobile app or an automated script that is trying to gamify and take advantage of the service provided by the application.

Well, to identify the **WHAT**, developers tend to resort to an API key that usually they hard-code in the code of their mobile app. Some developers go the extra mile and compute the key at run-time in the mobile app, thus it becomes a runtime secret as opposed to the former approach when a static secret is embedded in the code.

The above write-up was extracted from an article I wrote, entitled *WHY DOES YOUR MOBILE APP NEED AN API KEY?*, and that you can read in full [here](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key), that is the first article in a series of articles about API keys.

### Mobile App Attestation

The role of a Mobile App Attestation solution is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered with, is not running in a rooted device, not being instrumented by a framework like xPosed or Frida, not being MitM attacked, and this is achieved by running an SDK in the background. The service running in the cloud will challenge the app, and based on the responses it will attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on, thus the SDK will never be responsible for any decisions.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo.

[MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/)

> An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at Approov(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.

## SUMMARY

In the end, the solution to use in order to protect your API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.

## DO YOU WANT TO GO THE EXTRA MILE?

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.